# Is it permissible to build a building taller than Kaaba around it?

Tags: shiism, kaabah

I have heard that it is not permissible to make any buildings taller than Kaaba around it.  For instance there is a very tall clock as a very tall building which has been built so taller than Kaaba. (Shia view).

I was wondering if there is any narrations regarding this issue? If so, what could be the reason that we should not make any building taller than Kaaba?

Answer (score 6):

According to a logical principle, it is mandatory for Muslims to keep the revere (respect) of Kaaba. Actually whatever leads to disrespect the Kaaba (or to decreases its hugeness,) could be Haram. Since for instance if some groups build a tower or building taller than Kaaba (around it), hence rationally it could reduce the magnitude of Kaaba (at its apparent); how come?

Because the taller building, unwanted, would distract the Hojjaj (Hajjis) (and attracts their attention during Tawaaf) ... as a very huge building that Kaaba would be looked so smaller than that building in the view of the Hojjaj.
(As I saw that from near: When you are in Masjed-al-Haram, unwanted your looking ...)

Therefore its height (unwanted) would not allow Hojaj to concentrate on the Kaaba (to focus on praying and Tawaf and ...) completely even for example when they are saying prayers, perhaps its height would lead to distract … (Of course not always, but at many times...) And likewise whoever intents to go to the Kaaba, at the first sight, the height of the tall building will attract his/her attention.

**In accordance with a narration from Imam Baqer (a.s.), he mentioned that it is not an appropriate act to build a building taller than Kaaba; As a result we can say that according to Shia,  it is a Makruh act to build a building taller than Kaaba around it.**

> Imam Muhammad Baqer (A.S.):
>
> … and it is not suitable that somebody builds a structure (building)
>   taller than Kaaba. (Koleini, Muhammad ibn Yaqub, Al-Kaafi (Pg.230). To
>   see the complete address of the narration and also more information,
>   you can refer to the source below.)

---

**Source:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa34772#) (in Farsi)

Comment: +1 vote for the hadith! I may complete your answer in a later chance!

Comment: it is very kind of you that paid attention to my response. I would be grateful to see your more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense tbh. Erdogan, the president of Turkey, for instance also let a couple of skyscrapers get demolished, because there were mosques near them and the skyscrapers were ruining the skyline of Istanbul that is known for the mosques. If you look at the skyline of Makkah you can't see the Kaaba, only hotels and malls. There's no need for a Hadith even to know that this is morally incorrect. May Allah (s.w.t.) guide us to ther right path

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for mentioning the narration from Imam Baqir (a.s.). Naturally we feel that those buildings are offensive and disrespectful towards the holy Ka'ba. It's the devil's work. In earlier times churches and mosques were the tallest buildings, because religion was the centre of people's lives. Later bank buildings and other commercial companies took their place, thus expressing the worldly power of money. The more important, the more visible its signs. The desires of this world are overruling the spiritual life, we even see its signs in the holiest place on earth!